# Is God talking with God in Psalm 45:7?

Tags: psalms, linguistics

> You have loved righteousness and hated wickedness; Therefore God, Your God, has anointed you with the oil of joy above your companions. Ps 45:7

A recent answer suggested God is talking to God here. It would seem there are only two entities in this verse - one is 'you' the other is 'God'.

Regardless of the *upgrade* this passage received in Hebrews 1:9 which was brought to point to Christ, what is happening here in the Psalm - who is talking to whom?

Comment: It is a grammatically possible interpretation of both the [Greek and Hebrew](http://www.greekdoc.com/polyglot/ps45.html#v7), inasmuch as, on one hand, Hebrew nouns do not vary with regard to grammatical case, and, on the other, the Septuagintal version of the Psalms consistently renders the vocative of *God* through the nominative; similarly for Jerome's Latin Vulgate, since ancient Greeks and Romans were notoriously polytheistic, and, whenever invoking a god, they would use its given name, rather than the generic noun for *deity*.

Comment: @user48152 - Your question appears to reference the NASB version of Psalm 45. * If you continue to read the NASB version of Psalm 45:16 "In place of your fathers will be your sons; You shall make them princes in all the earth" - Why would this Psalm be addressing God? - Elohim does not have multiple Fathers/Ancestors.

Answer (score 3):

I'd interpret the psalm Messianically.

Psalm 45

> For the director of music. To the tune of “Lilies.” Of the Sons of Korah. A maskil.  A **wedding** song.
>
> 1 My heart is stirred by a noble theme
> as I recite my verses for the **king**;

The psalm is a Jewish royal wedding song.

> 2 **You** are the **most** excellent of men
> and your **lips** have been anointed with **grace**,
> since God has blessed you **forever**.

Jesus claimed to be greater than King Solomon in Matthew 12:42

> The Queen of the South will rise at the judgment with this generation and condemn it; for she came from the ends of the earth to listen to Solomon's wisdom, and now something greater than **Solomon** is here.

John 1:17

> For the law was given through Moses; **grace** and truth came through Jesus Christ.

Luke 4:22

> All spoke well of Him and marveled at the **gracious** words that came from His **lips**. "Isn't this the son of Joseph?" they asked.

There is strong evidence that the "You" in verse 2 refers to the Messiah.

Verse 7:

> You have loved righteousness and hated wickedness; Therefore God, Your God, has anointed you With the oil of joy above your companions.

Hebrews 1 makes it clear that Psalm 45:7 is messianic.

> 8 But about the **Son** he says,
> “Your throne, O God, will last for ever and ever;
> a scepter of justice will be the scepter of your kingdom.
> 9 You have loved righteousness and hated wickedness;
> therefore God, your God, has set you above your companions
> by anointing you with the oil of joy.”

Is God talking with God in Psalm 45:7?

Not exactly. The psalmist addresses the Son:

> You [the Son] have loved righteousness and hated wickedness; Therefore God, Your God [the Father], has anointed you With the oil of joy above your companions.

Comment: Where does ‘son’ come from the text? It is reapplied in Hebrews, but not here

Comment: Do you believe that the epistle of Hebrews was inspired?

Comment: We must stick to context. The Psalm looks forward - but what to was not yet made clear. Interpreting the Ps to refer to the son is eisegetical. many Ps's were 're-applied' in the NT (which was inspired by many OT texts) - and there we may speak of the son. The Q is about the Psalm. So the Psalmist certainly does not address the son.

Comment: I believe this is called: pick and choose and exclude.

Comment: LOL ohh the irony! Is 53 debunks your theory - by sticking to the *context* of Ps 45:2 we know it isn't speaking of the Son.

Comment: It was not my theory. It was the theory of whoever wrote Hebrews.

Comment: Believe it or not. I upvoted your question when I saw the -2.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to the question is "Yes".  However, this question has arisen many time before here such as:

[Trying to understand the meaning/purpose when it comes to Psalm 45 use of the word "daughter"](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48805/trying-to-understand-the-meaning-purpose-when-it-comes-to-psalm-45-use-of-the-wo/48814#48814)

[Did the writer of Psalm 45:6 think that the human king to which this verse was addressed was Almighty God?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48523/did-the-writer-of-psalm-456-think-that-the-human-king-to-which-this-verse-was-a/48527#48527)

[Who is the God of God in Psalm 45:8?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/6202/who-is-the-god-of-god-in-psalm-458/6203#6203)

In Ps 45 we can be either understood as a bridal hymn (as was common by some interpreters) or better, as a Messianic Anthem of praise as does its citing in Hebrews 1:7, 8 where Jesus and the Father are talking with each other.  Both are called "God" in Ps 45:7 as per the LXX, ὁ θεός, ὁ θεός σου = "God, Your God".

The phenomenon of God speaking to God, or more specifically, the LORD speaking to the LORD is seen in other places:

- Zech 2:6-12 – the LORD (= YHWH) claims three times that He has been sent by the LORD.
- Isa 48:11-16 – again, the LORD has been sent by the LORD.
- Isa 63:7-16 – the LORD (described as a Father) sends His divine servant (the angel of His presence) and His Holy Spirit who is grieved (compare Ps 78:40).
- Ex 23:20 – the angel of the LORD’s presence has the power to forgive sin (but will not).  This and the previous reference clearly make the angel of the presence the pre-incarnate Jesus.
- Hos 1:7 – the LORD saves by the LORD their God.
- Prov 30:1-4 – the Son of God is as unfathomable as God Himself.
- Ps 45 (quoted by Heb 1) talks about the “Son” being God in addition to God the Father.

[See also Psalm 110 – “The LORD says to my Lord” – Jesus asked about this Psalm on how someone could be both Son and Lord of David – see Matt 22:44, Mark 12:36, Luke 20:42, Acts 2:34.]

Answer (score 2):

Here are the Hebrew text (HEB), the Greek LXX and the respective literal English translations of the relevant part of the verse ([Psalm 45:7](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?book=Psa&chapter=45&verse=7) NET)

> [HEB] **עַל־כֵּ֤ן מְשָׁחֲךָ֡ אֱלֹהִ֣ים אֱ֭לֹהֶיךָ** (Therefore
> anointed you God your God)
>  [LXX] δια τουτο εχρισεν σε ο θεος ο
> θεος σου (Therefore anointed you God your God)

The "you" in the Psalm is the Davidic king, celebrating his marriage to a lovely princess.

The reason why the noun God appears twice is that the first time it simply points to God (Heb: אֱלֹהִ֣ים; Grk: ο θεος - the determinative article in Greek makes it clear that it is YHWH God and no other); the second time it is specified that it is "your God" (Heb: אֱ֭לֹהֶיךָ; ο θεος σου), that is the King's God.

While certainly this Psalm, and in particular this verse, is undestood by Christians as a reference to the Messiah-King, **the God of which verse 7 speaks (even twice) is only the One and Only God, YHWH**.

**P.S.** The case is probably different different with verse 6.

Answer (score 1):

I would add there are other plurals as well that point to a complex unity of God.  Arnold Fructhenbaum is a good source for the grammar. I have paraphrased how he explained the plurals below.

Genesis 20:13 Elohim they caused me to wander
Genesis 35:7 Elohim revealed themselves
2 Samuel 7:23 whom Elohim they went to redeem for themselves
Psalm 58:11 Elohim they judge on earth
Joshua 24:19 holy gods
Psalm 149:2 let Israel be glad in his makers
Ecc. 12:1 remember your creators
Isaiah 54:5 your makers is your husbands
Deut. 4:7 Gods so near